# Who is the parent?

Tags: qml

I have a qml app which is created via two separate ways.
1) via a c++ code during startup
2) via my main.qml as one of the tabs.

Inside the qml app I want to know who is my parent so that I can decide if I should stay on my current page or load some other qml.  How to know who is the parent to take such decision?

Answer (score 1):

This question is difficult to answer for a few reasons. Notably, it's not especially clear what you want. The simple answer to your question is that a QML element always has access to it's parent via the exposed parent property that exists on all objects.  If your question is more complicated as it appears then you need to rephrase the question to better clarify what you actually want.